# How to include Cost Method into Facebook Atlas Reporting API?

Tags: facebook, api, atlas

According to the atlas api reference [WebMediaReportColumn](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/atlas-api/reporting/reference/value-sets/WebMediaReportColumn/), if i can specify a PackageName, there should be a way to specify a cost data

```
Specifies the name of the package.
For single-placement packages, the package name is the same as the placement name. The    
PackageName column should be used in reports that include cost data.enter code here
```

But how? i cant find any Cost Method within the [WebMediaReportColumn](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/atlas-api/reporting/reference/value-sets/WebMediaReportColumn/)

And can someone tag this question with "facebook-atlas-api"? Because "Facebook" is too generalize.

Answer (score 0):

The Atlas reporting API will let you get costing information out in these reports, but only if you've setup costing information using Cost Package objects in the Atlas data model.  Cost Packages are a way for you to model how the advertiser and publisher have agreed on pricing for the ad campaign.  Atlas lets you model a number of different kinds of agreements, including flat CPM, CPC, CPA, free/bonus, CPM blend, etc.  Once this costing information has been setup for your campaign, you can pull reports that will give you the amount that has been spent to date.